# Creating two elements with vw to create 100vw doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create 2 simple divs, one of `80vw` and the other of `20vw` to create two divs side by side.

For some reason this doesn't work:

```
<div style="background:black; height:100vh; width:50vw; display:inline-block;">50vw</div>
<div style="background:red; height:100vh; width:50vw;display:inline-block;">50vw</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4hvrz4o1/

Answer (score -1):

[Switch to flexbox model](https://jsfiddle.net/4hvrz4o1/3/):

```
 <div style="display:flex">
     <div style="background:black; height:100vh; width:50vw; display:inline-block;">50vw</div>
     <div style="background:red; height:100vh; width:50vw;display:inline-block;">50vw</div>
 </div>
```

The original browser layout madness has a method to it, you just have to remember it. Personally, I find the the flexbox model more often aligns with my "way of thinking" about layout, so I use it more often. [Here's a cheat sheet](http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html) to common use cases, esp. the side-by-side case.

Comment: Ok but why mine doesn't work? It should work just fine without the container shouldn't it?

Comment: No, because the parent of those two `div` -- `<body>` -- has not been sized to _envelope_ them. In the traditional box layout model, you have to carefully ensure the parent always envelopes its children. Flex box still requires a parent that envelopes the children, but it handles more of the calculation for you. You might also consider [CSS Grid](https://tutorialzine.com/2017/03/css-grid-vs-flexbox) if this is going to be a full-page layout.

Answer (score -2):

Add a parent element with `width:100vw` and child element as `width:50%`

Here is updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/4hvrz4o1/2/